# How Eclipse can compile jsp fragments whose variables are declared in another file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, include, fragment

I want completion and compilation erros on eclipse for jsp fragments in eclipse.
How can i have completion on test2.jnc for this files :

```
<%-- test1.jsp --%>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%
String ma_variable = "";
%>
<%@ include file="test2.jnc" %>
<html>
 <body><h1><%=ma_variable%></h1></body>
</html>
```

And the interpreted included file that was on error in eclipse (ma_variable cannot be resolved) :

```
<%-- test2.jnc --%>
ma_variable = "Hello World!";
```

If i launch that file in tomcat, all goes fine, but eclipse don't find ma_variable in the test2.jnc scope...

any idea? I "googled" but i did'nt find anything relevent...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to use scriptlets. Use JSTL:

```
<c:set var="ma_variable" value="Hello World!" />

<h1>${ma_variable}</h1>
```

Comment: If this is the only way to do the trick, I will pass long nights to do this pharaonic work...

Answer (score 0):

try adding .jnc extension to JSP editor of eclipse

Comment: Try to include .jnc file after the declaration

Comment: oops, you're right, my "demo" files don't work, i just edit it, but the issue is the same :)